# How do I use Ionic's slide box to change the route and controller?

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

When I change slides in the slidebox, I would like the UI router to reflect these changes within the routes so that different controllers for each slide can be loaded. Currently, this is not being detected when I slide through the slide box.

When I manually try to change the state by using the `$ionicScrollDelegate` as reference, I see myself constantly reloading the `slide-box` entity itself, causing some funky glitches and black space transitions between each slide.

What is the best strategy to let UI router reflect changes in the slide?